# Errors: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Below is my query which gives me OrderBy error. I tried looking up for solutions but none of them work. Please help me understand what cound be wrong here.

P.S: This is in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

```
SELECT RIGHT(email_address, LEN(email_address) - CHARINDEX('@', email_address)) as domain,
COUNT(email_address) as domain_count
FROM   MY_DE
WHERE  LEN(email_address) > 0
GROUP BY RIGHT(email_address, LEN(email_address) - CHARINDEX('@', email_address))
ORDER BY domain_count DESC
```

Comment: This query has no CTEs or subqueries or inline functions and it is not creating a view.  Is there something you are leaving out?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your query into another select statement, then you can apply order by:

```
SELECT domain, domain_count
From (
   SELECT RIGHT(email_address, LEN(email_address) - CHARINDEX('@', email_address)) as domain,
   COUNT(email_address) as domain_count
   FROM   MY_DE
   WHERE  LEN(email_address) > 0
   GROUP BY RIGHT(email_address, LEN(email_address) - CHARINDEX('@', email_address))
) TableName
ORDER BY domain_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but now its gives me this error:
Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: I wants table name for subquery (I've corrected SQL in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

In SFMC there's a trick to get the order-by clause to work -- just add a `top 100 percent`:

```sql
SELECT top 100 percent
  x.domain
, x.domain_count
From (
   SELECT 
     RIGHT(email_address, LEN(email_address) - CHARINDEX('@', email_address)) as domain
   , COUNT(*) as domain_count
   FROM MY_DE
   WHERE 
   isnull(email_address,'') != ''
   GROUP BY 
   RIGHT(email_address, LEN(email_address) - CHARINDEX('@', email_address))
) x
ORDER BY x.domain_count DESC
```